# How to ignore empty Optional field during Jackson Serialization

Tags: java, java-8, jackson

I want to ignore an Optional field value during serialization if its value is null.

> Employee.java

```
class Employee {

private String firstName;

private String secondName;

public Optional<String> getFirstName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(firstName);
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public Optional<String> getSecondName() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(secondName);
}
public void setSecondName(String secondName) {
    this.secondName = secondName;
}
}
```

have configured Jackson as below:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(employee));
```

The serialization method is giving below output:

```
{"firstName":"foo", "secondName":null}
```

But we want result like below:

```
{"firstName":"foo"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) for `Optional` states:

> Optional is primarily intended for use as a method return type where there is a clear need to represent "no result," and where using null is likely to cause errors.

In other words, you shouldn't be using `Optional` here in the first place.

However, if you still want to, `@JsonInclude(NON_ABSENT)` ([doc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_ABSENT)) should work just fine.

Comment: I used objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) to resolve this but later discovered NON_ABSENT is more accurate in Optional context.
Hoping it wont mess up with non Optional fields of DTO.

Comment: Both `NON_ABSENT` and `NON_EMPTY` have good javadoc entries that explain when exactly they do and don't ignore a field. If you are worried about the setting affecting other objects you didn't intend to, you can use the annotation on one dto object or even one field, instead of on the whole `ObjectMapper`.

Comment: I dont want to edit dto class, the other way of doing it could be creating a custom serializer for the Optional type that ignores empty Optionals during serialization and registering the custom serializer with Jackson. But I think that would be unnecessary and I should go with your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom serializer:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class EmployeeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Employee> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Employee employee, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        
        employee.getFirstName().ifPresent(firstName -> {
            try {
                jsonGenerator.writeStringField("firstName", firstName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // Handle the exception
            }
        });

        employee.getSecondName().ifPresent(secondName -> {
            try {
                jsonGenerator.writeStringField("secondName", secondName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // Handle the exception
            }
        });

        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then add this annotation to your `Employee` class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = EmployeeSerializer.class)
```

Here you can read more:
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Hope it helps!

Comment: No need for a custom serializer, especially not one for *the whole object*. Just use `@JsonInclude(NON_ABSENT)`

Comment: @Jorn you are absolutely right. That was just the first solution that came to my mind, so I specified that he CAN do it that way because I was almost certain that there could be a better way to do so.

Comment: @tamtejszystan is there any way of doing it without editing Employee class?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite message converters to configure global serialization settings

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    /**/
    
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        Iterator<HttpMessageConverter<?>> iterator = converters.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            HttpMessageConverter<?> next = iterator.next();
            if (next instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = jackson2HttpMessageConverter.getObjectMapper();
                objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            } else if (next instanceof MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    /**/

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).